# Parallelize a for loop that sums up different elements from an array

Tags: c++, multithreading

First of all I'm not a C++ master, as you will probably notice even from the small portion of code beneath.

I'm working on writing a simple [Mean Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) Python module in C++ using the [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann) library.

I'm using Cython as an interface to C++, passing the numpy arrays (`samples` and `seeds`) as `double*`. You can find the full code on [github](https://github.com/w00zie/mean_shift_cpp/tree/parallel) (at your own risk).

This is my full module:

```
#include "mean_shift.h"
#include "nanoflann/include/nanoflann.hpp"
#include "KDTreeVectorOfVectorsAdaptor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::vector<double> vofd;
typedef std::vector<vofd> vofv;
typedef KDTreeVectorOfVectorsAdaptor<vofv, double> KDTree;
typedef std::pair<vofd, size_t> meanPair;
typedef std::vector<meanPair> vecPair;
typedef std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double> > searchResultPair;

const int SAMPLES_DIM = 3;
const int max_leaf = 30;

vofv fromPointerToVOV(double* array, int N, int M) {
    /*
    *   needed to cast the double* samples numpy array
    *   to something understandable by the nanoflann lib
    */
    int index = 0;
    vofv temp;
    temp.resize(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        temp[i].resize(M);
        for(int j=0; j<M; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = array[index];
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }
    return(temp);
}

double* pointsWithinAndMean(size_t nMatches, searchResultPair matches,
        double* samples, int n_jobs=1)
        /*
         *      COMMENTS HERE
         */
        {
    double* meanArray = new double[3];
    meanArray[0] = 0;
    meanArray[1] = 0;
    meanArray[2] = 0;
    double x, y, z;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
        x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
        y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
        z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
    }
    meanArray[0] = x / nMatches;
    meanArray[1] = y / nMatches;
    meanArray[2] = z / nMatches;

    return(meanArray);
}

vecPair meanShift(double* samples, double* seeds, int xSamples, int ySamples,
        int numSeeds, double bandwidth, int max_iter, int n_jobs=1)
        /**
        *       COMMENTS HERE
         */
        {

    const double search_radius = bandwidth * bandwidth;
    int iter = 0;
    vofd myMeanVector;
    vofv samplesVector;
    nanoflann::SearchParams params;
    searchResultPair matches;
    double* old_mean = new double[3];
    double* mean_array = new double[3];
    vecPair listOfCenters;
    //
    samplesVector = fromPointerToVOV(samples, xSamples, ySamples);
    KDTree kd_tree = KDTree(SAMPLES_DIM, samplesVector, max_leaf);
    kd_tree.index->buildIndex();
    //
    myMeanVector.resize(3);
    mean_array[0] = seeds[0];
    mean_array[1] = seeds[1];
    mean_array[2] = seeds[2];
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < numSeeds; i = i + 3) {
        mean_array[0] = seeds[i];
        mean_array[1] = seeds[i + 1];
        mean_array[2] = seeds[i + 2];
        while (true) {
            size_t nMatches = kd_tree.index->radiusSearch(&mean_array[0],
                    search_radius, matches, params);
            old_mean = mean_array;
            mean_array = pointsWithinAndMean(nMatches, matches, samples, n_jobs);
            if ((calcNorm(mean_array, old_mean) < (0.001 * 5.5))
                or iter == max_iter) {
                iter = 0;
                myMeanVector[0] = mean_array[0];
                myMeanVector[1] = mean_array[1];
                myMeanVector[2] = mean_array[2];
                listOfCenters.push_back(make_pair(myMeanVector, nMatches));
                break;
            }
            iter = iter + 1;
        }
    }
    return(listOfCenters);

}

double calcNorm(double* arrayA, double* arrayB)
/*
 *
 */
{
    double norm, normx, normy, normz;
    normx = (arrayA[0] - arrayB[0]) * (arrayA[0] - arrayB[0]);
    normy = (arrayA[1] - arrayB[1]) * (arrayA[1] - arrayB[1]);
    normz = (arrayA[2] - arrayB[2]) * (arrayA[2] - arrayB[2]);
    norm = sqrt(normx + normy + normz);

    return (norm);
}
```

Now, since I'm trying to boost the performance, I thought that I could improve the `pointsWithinAndMean` method, which is the core of the convergence of the Mean Shift module.
I thought about parallelizing the `for` loop inside the function, finding an efficient method to concurrently access the `matches[i].first` variable and maybe using an `std::accumulator` on the `x,y,z` variables.
I know that the elements in a `vector` are stored in contiguous portions of memory but I hoped someone could revise my code and give me some hints on how to make the whole module more efficient.
Is there a way to parallelize something? I'm kinda new to concurrent C++.

Comment: I'm wondering if this should be part of the code-review site. Should this not be on stackoverflow?

Comment: Don't know, hope the mods will help

Comment: Usually the mods won't be required to re-open this. Seems like you fixed your question. Please read the following before posting your next question: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Comment: Is it nanoflann that requires a vector of vectors? Sigh. That is terribly inefficient for the sole benefit of being able to write `v[i][j]`. Even a small image of 1024x1024 requires 1025 memory allocations where one suffices.

Answer (score 2):

#### Parallelizing the loop

Contrary to the current code you have on Github, when parallelizing this loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
    x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
    y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
    z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
}
```

It's probably better to treat the entirety as a single parallel loop.  `samples[3 * (matches[i].first)]`, `samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1]` and `samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2]` will typically all be allocated in the same cache line, and as a general rule we'd prefer to read a single cache line only once. To get (at least closer to) that, we could write the code like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
    x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
    y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
    z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
}
```

We're left with a couple of difficulties there though. The first is that Open MP will (at least with most compilers) require that we rewrite the loop to use an `int` as its index:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
    x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
    y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
    z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
}
```

Second, we have the same variables for `x`, `y` and `z` being shared between iterations of the loop, which is likely to slow things down. Fortunately, OpenMP has a directive specifically for situations like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x, y, z)
for (int i = 0; i < nMatches; i = i + 1) {
    x = x + samples[3 * (matches[i].first)];
    y = y + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 1];
    z = z + samples[3 * (matches[i].first) + 2];
}
```

All that having been said, my guess is that executing this code in parallel is unlikely to increase speed much (at least on a typical single-socket machine). The content of the loop is sufficiently simple that a single core can probably saturate the memory channels, so unless other cores have completely separate memory channels, there's little chance of multiple threads speeding this up much.

#### Useless comments

Comments like:

```
    /*
     *      COMMENTS HERE
     */
```

and:

```
/*
 *
 */
```

...are worse than useless, adding noise while imparting no useful information.

#### Notation

Unless you have quite a specific reason for using something like: `0.001 * 5.5`, I'd tend to believe that `5.5e-3` is probably more readable to most people.

#### Indentation

I had to read through this a couple of times:

```
        if ((calcNorm(mean_array, old_mean) < (0.001 * 5.5))
            or iter == max_iter) {
            iter = 0;
            myMeanVector[0] = mean_array[0];
            myMeanVector[1] = mean_array[1];
            myMeanVector[2] = mean_array[2];
            listOfCenters.push_back(make_pair(myMeanVector, nMatches));
            break;
        }
```

...to feel certain that it was even correct. If the `if` statement is on multiple lines, I think it's probably better to put the opening brace on its own line as well. So, we could have either:

```
    if ((calcNorm(mean_array, old_mean) < 5.5e-3) or iter == max_iter) {
```

...or else:

```
        if ((calcNorm(mean_array, old_mean) < 5.5e-3)
            or iter == max_iter) 
        {
```

#### Modifying variables

I realize that you're probably accustomed to things like: `i = i + 3` and `i = i + 1` from other languages, but in C and C++ these are normally expressed as: `i += 3` and `++i` respectively. These have two obvious advantages: 1) people recognize them, and 2) they can't easily be misread as (obviously false) logical assertions (i.e., a claim that `i` is equal to `i + 3`, rather than assigning `i+3` to the location currently holding `i`).

#### Loops

It seems to me that this loop:

```
    while (true) {
        size_t nMatches = kd_tree.index->radiusSearch(&mean_array[0],
                search_radius, matches, params);
        old_mean = mean_array;
        mean_array = pointsWithinAndMean(nMatches, matches, samples, n_jobs);
        if ((calcNorm(mean_array, old_mean) < (0.001 * 5.5))
            or iter == max_iter) {
            iter = 0;
            myMeanVector[0] = mean_array[0];
            myMeanVector[1] = mean_array[1];
            myMeanVector[2] = mean_array[2];
            listOfCenters.push_back(make_pair(myMeanVector, nMatches));
            break;
        }
        iter = iter + 1;
    }
```

...would probably be better written as a `for` loop:

```
for (int iter = 0; iter < max_iter; ++iter) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Memory Leaks

Right now, you have:

```
double* old_mean = new double[3];
double* mean_array = new double[3];
```

These are local variables that are neither returned to the caller nor deleted before the function returns, so you're leaking memory on each call to this function (albeit, only a little). There seems to be no reason to use dynamic allocation here, so these would probably be better written as:

```
double old_mean[3];
double mean_array[3];
```

...but see below for what I think is probably an even better way to do things.

#### Data Organization

What you really seem to have is arrays of points, where each point has X, Y, and Z coordinates. It probably won't help performance (but probably won't hurt it either) if you do something like:

```
struct point { 
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
};

point old_mean;
point mean;
```

In this case, instead of dealing with `mean[0]`, `mean[1]` and `mean[2]`, you deal with `mean.X`, `mean.Y` and `mean.Z`. This also restores the ability to assign the values involved, which you're using (and I suppose is why you dynamically allocated the arrays to start with). The difference is that in this case you're getting what you probably want instead of leaking memory, and ending up with `mean` and `old_mean` being aliases for the same actual storage.